# Why my Excel is not getting proper formatted when exporting with given html data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, xslt

I am having html data which I want to export to Excel using jquery.
My jquery code is:

```
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {

var dd=<div>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="bordercollapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">FirstName</th>
        <th scope="col">LastName</th>
        <th scope="col">Gender</th>
        <th scope="col">Team_Name</th>
        <th scope="col">MobileNumber</th>
        <th scope="col">Alternative_Number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gautam</td><td>Naik</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>CCI Internal</td>
        <td>3537835522</td>
        <td>8244225654</td>
   </tr>
<table>
 <div>;    


window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + dd);
//e.preventDefault();
});
```

this is working to the point where it downloads an xsl file but contains this data.

[image]

When I tried passing the same html data to http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm which converts the html data to excel data it was giving me correct output i.e
[image]

what changes do I need to do in my jquery code to get it work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrieve values of each td using jquery and post it in form of csv using ajax to server. At server write csv values to excel file